# Hibernate Criteria : selection from two tables with Foreign key relationship?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have in my mysql databse 2 tables :

```
1.teacher(id(pk),name,phone,email)
2.student(id(pk),teacher'sid(FK),name,phone,email)
```

The student table has a Foreign Key , teacher'sid ,that refrences to teacher.id .

I want to select the teachers that their id(teachers.id) is same as (student.teacher'sid) where student.name = "Steven".

I have made two classes with the same class name and properties as the table,and i have configured the mapping.

```
@Entity
class teacher {
@Id
int id;
String name;
String phone;
String email;
}

@Entity
class student {
@Id
int id;
int teachersid;
String name;
String phone;
String email;
}
```

I am able to select the student that his name is "steven" by:

```
Criteria q = session.createCriteria(student.class).add(
                Restrictions.eq("name", "stevens"));
```

How can retreive the teacher of "Steven"?
Something like

```
(select * from teacher(where teacher.id = student.teachersid(where student.name="stevens")))
```

,but with Hibernate Criteria Api.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Teacher .class,"tchr");
c.createCriteria("students", "s");//Teacher class should contain students collection
c.add(Restrictions.eq("s.name", "Ashok"));
List l=c.list();
```

Hope this will help you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How i do that? something like:student students?if i do it like this i must change the mapping in hibernate.cfg.xml?I have it as         <mapping class="teacher" />
<mapping class="doctor" />

Comment: You need below property in Teacher.java        @OneToMany(targetEntity=Student.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="teacher")
@Cascade(value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();    

You need below property in Student.java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="colg_id")
private College college;

You need to have setters and getters of these properties in both the classes.

Comment: In the first row isn't it session.createCriteria?

Comment: yeah..it is session.createCriteria

Comment: When i try to compile it it says:                                  Type mismatch: cannot convert from CascadeType to CascadeType[]

Comment: You need to import CascadeType  from hibernate package not from JPA package. You might be importing that from JPA package so you are getting that issue.

Comment: These are my imports:                                                     import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;                      The problem remains!

Comment: send your code somehow( like http://pastebin.com/ ) so that I can better understand the problem

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2YyJac8x     doctor.java           http://pastebin.com/hKfs8ZUU        patient.java          http://pastebin.com/zfeXjtY1     webservice.java  http://pastebin.com/bHqbpfSg hibernate.cfg.xml                      This code works but i want to find the doctor that his id is same as the patient.docid where patient.phone is "6984356722"

Comment: The patient gives his phone number as password and then he takes back by the webservice his doctors phone,email etc.So i want to select the doctor,that his id is equals to the patient.docid ,where the patient is he with the specified phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Your Hibernate entity class does not reflect the relation between the tables correctly.
The Student entity should look something similar to

```
@Entity
class student {
@Id
int id;
teacher teach;
String name;
String phone;
String email;
}
```

Once you modified your entities correctly, then hibernate automatically issues a join between the tables.

Comment: But i want the student to have only one teacher.The teacher can have many students.

Comment: Add the relationship entity annotations accordingly. See link http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use the teacher entity as main entity and apply a sqlRestriction to filter this table. 
I think you cannot use criterias and restrictions directly from the Students class because what you what to retrieve are the teacher entities and there's no mapping in this direction teacher -> student.

I think this will work for you:

```
Criteria q = session.createCriteria(teacher.class)
          .add( Restrictions.sqlRestriction("exists (select 1 
                from student_table s where    s.teachersid = {alias}.id 
                and s.student_name=?", "stevens", Hibernate.STRING) )
```